# Existing module for logged in user image upload

Tags: 7, media, files

I'm looking to build an image upload website. The only feature needed is the ability for logged in users to upload images.

Is there an existing module for this?

I could just build a custom module for a form; but i wanted to find a decent module to build this before investing time into it.

Required:

- Image upload restricted by user role
- Each Image upload becomes either node

Some wants:

- Image cropping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that in different ways, you can use the [media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module to create image galleries, remember if you use that module installing [Styles](http://drupal.org/project/styles)

Comment: Not totally getting what you're saying after the comma. Did you mean i have to install the styles module in order to use the media module?